# LPTHW Ex51 with image upload

Tags: python, beginner

Here's what I ended up with for *Learning Python the Hard Way Ex 51* with image upload (save and display).

The form:

```
<div style="margin:300px;border:1px solid #000">
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload">
A Greeting: <input type="text" name="greet">
<br/>
Your Name: <input type="text" name="name">
<br/>
Image file: <input type="file" name="myfile" />
<br/>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</div>
```

The app:

```
import web
import shutil
import os

urls = (
    '/', 'Index',
    '/images/(.*)', 'images' #this is where the image folder is located....
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

render = web.template.render('templates/', base="layout")

class images:
    def GET(self,name):
        ext = name.split(".")[-1] # Gather extension

        cType = {
            "png":"images/png",
            "jpg":"images/jpeg",
            "gif":"images/gif",
            "ico":"images/x-icon"            }

        if name in os.listdir('images'):  # Security
            web.header("Content-Type", cType[ext]) # Set the Header
            return open('images/%s'%name,"rb").read() # Notice 'rb' for reading images
        else:
            raise web.notfound()

class Index:
    def GET(self):
        form = web.input(name="Nobody", greet=None)
        return render.upload_form()

    def POST(self):
        x = web.input(myfile={},name="Nobody", greet="Hello")
        file_name = x['myfile'].filename # This is the filename
        with open('/Users/mikekilmer/Envs/env1/images/' + file_name, 'wb') as saved:
            shutil.copyfileobj(x['myfile'].file, saved) # save the file 
        greeting = "%s, %s" % (x.greet, x.name)

        file_value = x['myfile'].value # This is the file contents
        file_read = x['myfile'].file.read() # Or use a file(-like) object
        return render.index(greeting = greeting, file_name = file_name,
                            file_value = file_value, file_read = file_read)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The template:

```
$def with (greeting, file_name, file_value, file_read)

<div style="margin:300;">
$if greeting:
    I just wanted to say <em style="color: red; font-size: 1em;">$greeting</em>.
    <br/>
$else:
    <em>Hello</em>, world!
    <br/>
$if file_name:
    File name is <em style="color: red; font-size: 1em;">$file_name</em>.
    <br/>
$else:
    <em>No file name</em>, friends!
$if file_name:
    File value is <em style="color: green; font-size: 1em;">$file_name</em>.
    <br/>
$else:
    <em>No file value</em>, friends!   
    <br/>
$if file_read:
    File read is <em style="color: blue; font-size: 1em;">$file_name</em>.
    <br/>
$else:
    <em>No file read</em>, friends!   
    <br/>
<img src="./images/$file_name"/>
</div>
```

The `layout` is as outlined in the book.

Why do `x['myfile'].filename`, `x['myfile'].value`, and `x['myfile'].file.read()` (which I'm only sending out of curiosity) all seem to return nothing more than the file name (at least in the template)?

Comment: The `upload_form` template seems to be missing. Could you add it to make it easier to run the code and answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by my comment above, a template is missing. Once it's available, I'll try to expand my answer to cover your question.

In the meantime, please find below a few comments:

- Style ([PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/))

  - Try to split lines longer than 80 characters.
  - Inline comments: two spaces should follow the code and the comment should start with `#` followed by another space.
  - Use to blank lines before each class declaration
  - Use capital letters to name classes (`images` -> `Images`)
  - Arguments:

    - Use a space after each `,` (`argument1, argument2`)
    - Do not use any space around keyword arguments (`argument=value`)
  - Use spaces around binary operators (`string % (variable,)`
  - Dictionaries

    - Use a space after `:`
    - The closing brace should not have so much whitespace. Preferably move it to its own line.
  - Try to have imports in alphabetical order
- Add docstrings ([PEP257](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/))

Other comments:

- `form` variable is assigned, but never used. I don't know much about the `web` module, but this doesn't look right.

Comment: Added the form. You're right. That form variable assignment is left over from previous code. Thanks for referring me back to `PEP8` and `PEP257`.

Comment: Looking again at the template, it seems `$file_name` is being used in places where `$file_value` or `$file_read` should be used instead. That's the reason all values seem to be the same.